# Getting Probleam while sending message using SMTP in Java?

Tags: java

Hi I am using SMTP server working fing

- but when user invoking resetpassword we are sending mail but hear the mail getting different time.
- Example :- User invoking 1PM receiving mail at a time but mail time is different like 4PM i have tried but not getting Sir.
- can u please give some suggestions.
- Out message services Using SMTP Port : 25

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: Maybe the user is in West coast but your mail server is in East coast? :)

Comment: I'm in INDIA I'm using SNTP server port 25 I have given to frnd he is in US, Now he is using that application getting this problem

Comment: Hi Haifeng Zhang do u have any Idea.

Comment: The time zone is likely different and being adjusted to the user's local time.  What is the raw SMTP you are sending to the user.  There might be a header to specify the timezone on the date so it will be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify the time zone in a "Date" header. You've not specified any code or example headers in the mail, but the date header should look something like the following:

```
Date: Thu, 09 Feb 2017 13:44:16 +0100
```

+0100 specify the time zone GMT+1 which is similar to CET.

You can read more about time and date in RFC 2822 under "3.3. Date and Time Specification", https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt

Comment: I have not sending any header I'm giving only from to body. what i feel SMTP only take care about Time Zone right.

Comment: I'm not sure how you send your e-mail, but a correct Date header should give you the correct time. You either need to set it via the API you're using, or add your header manually. You will otherwise force the SMTP-server that you're sending to set a Date header. That server might have the wrong time zone.